# visual studio c# .NET Get, Set right? values 0

Tags: c#, math, logic, procedure

in the line I marked with "<-----" debugger gives me for hoehe,laenge,breite,ekpreis the value 0. Idk why, I am new in c#. Can u help me pls?

// Class clsBerechnung:

```
    public int Laenge { get; set; }

    public int Breite { get; set; }

    public int Hoehe { get; set; }

    public double Ekpreis { get; set; }

    public double Calculation()
    {
        double hilf = Oberflaeche(Laenge, Breite, Hoehe) / 1.52;    <---
        hilf = Math.Round(hilf * Ekpreis, 2);
        return hilf;
    }

    public double Oberflaeche(int laenge, int breite, int hoehe)
    {
        double hilf = 0;
        hilf = 2 * (laenge * hoehe) + 2 * (breite * hoehe) + (breite * laenge);
        hilf = hilf / 1000000;
        hilf = Math.Round(hilf * 0.8, 2);
        return hilf;
    }
```

// in frmMain:

```
    static clsBerechnung Berechnung = new clsBerechnung();

    Berechnung.Ekpreis = Convert.ToDouble(reader["EK-Preis"]);
    Berechnung.Laenge = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Länge"]);
    Berechnung.Breite = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Breite"]);
    Berechnung.Hoehe = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Höhe"]);

    lblOberflaeche.Text = "Oberfläche: " + Convert.ToString(Berechnung.Oberflaeche(Berechnung.Laenge, Berechnung.Breite, Berechnung.Hoehe)) + " m²";

lblLaufmeter.Text = "Laufmeter: " + Convert.ToString(Math.Round((Berechnung.Oberflaeche(Berechnung.Laenge, Berechnung.Breite, Berechnung.Hoehe) / 1.52),2));
```

// in frmErgebnis:

```
        static clsBerechnung Berechnung = new clsBerechnung();
        label1.Text = Convert.ToString(Berechnung.Calculation());
```

Is the logic correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the `Berechnung` members are static in `frmMain` and `frmErgebnis`, these are two different instances of the `clsBerechnung` class and the `Laenge`, `Breite`, and `Hoehe` properties are not static. So initializing these properties in `frmMain` does not affect those in `frmErgebnis`.

You either need to share a single instance of `clsBerechnung` between `frmMain` and `frmErgebnis` somehow or make the aforementioned properties and methods using them static.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dmitry.
How can share a single instance of clsBerechnung between the bother other classes? Any ideas?

Comment: Depending on `clsBerechnung` usage pattern. If only one instance through all the code is required, you may employ the Singleton pattern and declare the following in your `clsBerechnung` class: `static clsBerechnung instance = null; public static clsBerechnung Instance { get { if (instance == null) instance = new clsBerechnung; return instance} }`. This effectively provides the same functionality as just having the properties and methods static in your case.

Comment: If there should be several instances on the class, then you may just pass the `Berechnung` variable initialized in one form class to the other.